# Cocos2d-x setup on Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I want to start developing with C++ and Cocos2d-X, I am following the [tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Mac_OS_X) on their site, but when it fails when I run the Xcode project `cocos2d_tests.xcodeproj`. The error is `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'glfw3.h' file not found`.

Do I have to install this library before run the program? I have not done it because I have not found any requirements for running it.

Comment: This should work out of the "box". Perhaps re unzip and try again? Maybe something messed up. I tested this on 2 machines per the same tutorial and it works although I'm on XCode 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glfw3 library comes along with cocos2dx. it is present in external folder of root cocos2dx folder. Please check "User Header search Paths" settings inside Build Settings of your target project. It should contain following line

> $(SRCROOT)/../external/glfw3/include/mac

Comment: That was the issue, that line was not in this section. Thank you!